# paypal billing plan and agreement API, does it auto charge the credit card on each cycle

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Im trying to create a monthly subscription payment with paypal.

Im checking with paypal billing plans and agreements API
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/billing-plans-and-agreements/

once executed, is the charge to the credit card recurring, or every billing cycle we have to do something (if so what) ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has absolutely nothing to do with programming.

Comment: it does as it is a flow of the API, it has everything to do with programming

Comment: It looks like the purpose of the billing agreement is for you to setup a recurring charge with a customer defined by a billing plan.  PayPal should handle actually running the charge once you have executed the billing plan and agreement, but really your question is about how their product works, so I think the person to ask  is PayPal customer support.  If you have written some code, and it's not working as expected, you should add that to your question.

Comment: Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: obviously it's auto charging, otherwise, it wouldn't make many sense.

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri - Can you point to the PayPal documentation that states it is auto-charging? I have been looking for clarification on that point.